# Getting an error when entering valid data

Tags: python, validation, csv

The program I am writing takes a GTIN-8 code from the user, searches for it in a CSV file and asks for the quantity etc. When I write a valid GTIN code, it still acts as if I have entered a wrong GTIN and asks me to re-enter the code. It basically does the opposite of what I want it to do.

My CSV file is as follows:

```
GTIN        Name    Price
12312313    Kit-Kat 0.5
12345670    Mars    0.2
76543210    Bounty  0.3
34563670    Milky Way   0.4
```

And my code is as follows:

```
def quantityQuestion():
    with open("ChocolateCSV.csv", 'r') as file2:
        for row in csv.reader(file2):
            if str(gtinNum) in row:
                receipt.write(str(row) + "\n")
                receipt.write(str("- Quantity: " + quantity + "\n"))
                price = float(row[2]) * int(quantity)
                receipt.write("- Price: " + str("%.2f" % round(price, 2)) + "\n")
                restart()
                break
            elif str(gtinNum) not in row:
                print("The code entered could not be found - Please re-enter")
                gtinQuestion()

def gtinQuestion():
    global gtinNum
    gtinNum = input("Please enter the GTIN-8 Code of the product you would like to order:")

    if gtinNum.isdigit() == False or len(gtinNum) != 8:
        gtinQuestion()
    elif gtinNum.isdigit() == True and len(gtinNum) == 8:
        quantityQuestion()

gtinQuestion()
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Wild guess: put a `break` right after `gtinQuestion()` in the `for row in...` loop. Very generally speaking, when you do control flow by having multiple functions recursively call other functions, problems occur when functions higher up in the call stack don't terminate immediately after calling another function. If that sounds confusing, it's because it is; all the more reason to avoid this kind of design.

Comment: There appears to be a lot of irrelevant code here. Please take out anything not related to your error. [mcve]

Comment: @AndyG Edited to the relevant bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's erroring because you're checking the entered code on each line of the csv and showing the prompt if *any* of the lines don't match the entered code.

```
for row in csv.reader(file2):
    if str(gtinNum) in row:
        ...
        break
    elif str(gtinNum) not in row:
        print("The code entered could not be found - Please re-enter")
        gtinQuestion()
```

Instead you only want to show the prompt if *all* the lines don't match the entered code.

```
for row in csv.reader(file2):
    if str(gtinNum) in row:
        ...
        break
else:
    print("The code entered could not be found - Please re-enter")
    gtinQuestion()
```

Here, if the `if` inside the loop never matches, control will flow off the end of the `for` loop and execute the `else` statement.  If the `if` condition does match, it will `break` from the loop and the `else` clause won't be executed.

That being said, the way you're recursively calling the same function if conditions don't match is probably not a good design.

Here is another design that doesn't use recursive function calls, and doesn't require global variables.

```
def gtinQuestion():
    gtinNum = input("Please enter the GTIN-8 Code of the product you would like to order:")
    while not (gtinNum.isdigit() == True and len(gtinNum) == 8):
        gtinNum = input("Please enter the GTIN-8 Code of the product you would like to order:")
    return gtinNum

def main():
    gtinNumber = gtinQuestion()
    function_that_needs_gtinNumber(gtinNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks, the first edit worked. The indentation was off and im quite new to Python so this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw_input` instead of `input` so that you are getting a string back instead of an integer.

```
gtinNum = raw_input("Please enter the GTIN-8 Code of the product you would like to order:")
```

With `input`, when you provide an `int` as input, you get an `int` back, and `isdigit()` will cause an error... not sure why your implementation simply fails the test. ([demo](http://ideone.com/JCvZUv))

Answer (score 0):

Your real problem here is that you don't have the responsibilites of your program clearly separated - either in your mind or in the program.

To clearly define the different principles that you have:

1. Get a valid GTIN # from the user
2. Search the CSV file for the provided GTIN #
3. If the GTIN # is valid, get a valid quantity from the user
4. If the GTIN # is invalid, get another number
5. Display the total price to the user
6. Allow the user to restart.

If you write code before you have a clear understanding of the problem in front of you, you're going to end out in the pickle that you're in. Depending on your personality, you may like to work from the top down or the bottom up. With this problem, I'll go with the top-down solution. At it's most broad, you simply want to run the application until the user says they want to quit. Here's a simple program that does that:

```
wants_to_continue = True
while wants_to_continue:
    answer = input('Would you like to continue? [Y/n]: ')
    if answer.lower() in ('n', 'no', 'nyet', 'non'):
        wants_to_continue = False
```

Now, in *your* program you're getting a GTIN from the user and doing a two-step validation (or three, really). You're first checking to see if it *looks* like a valid GTIN, and then you're checking to see if it's actually found. But if you *instead* load the valid GTIN values first then you can actually just do it all in one fell swoop.

Knowing that, then, I would re-frame your objectives:

1. Read the data from the CSV file and convert it to useful format
2. Ask the user for a valid GTIN #
3. Ask the user for a valid quantity
4. Compute and display the total price
5. Ask the user if they'd like to repeat

Knowing that we're going to load your data first, here's one way to do that:

```
import csv

prices = {}
with open('prices.csv') as f:  # or ChocolateCSV.csv
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        prices[row['GTIN']] = row
    # You could replace this, and the prices = {} with
    # a dict comprehension
    # prices = {row['GTIN']:row for row in csv.DictReader(f)}
```

Unless you have a *massive* product database (several hundred thousand products - even 100k would be fine to do this way on a reasonable computer), this approach will be totally fine. Now that you have your data it's time to get a GTIN # from the user and see if it exists:

```
# Assuming that the prices were loaded by this point

wants_to_continue = True
while wants_to_continue:
    answer = input('Would you like to continue? [Y/n]: ')
    if answer.lower() in ('n', 'no', 'nyet', 'non'):
        wants_to_continue = False
    else:
        gtin = input('What product number would you like to order? ')
        product = prices.get(gtin)
        print(product)
```

From this point, all you should need to do is:

- display an error message if the product wasn't found (`if product is None:` then it wasn't found)
- if the product *is* found, ask the user for a valid quantity.
- Produce and display the resulting total.